# UITableViewAutomaticDimension and tags with names too long

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I was surprised to find out that we have a [uitableviewautomaticdim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uitableviewautomaticdim) tag, corresponding to the UITableViewAutomaticDimension. Do we really need it? Especially that the constant name is so long that I assume it's the reason the tag name is truncated.

**Edit** The tag seems to have been created by Community a couple of hours ago, or at least this is what the edit queue shows. Do we have an automated mechanism to create tags?
[image: tag create date]

Comment: Thanks for posting this burnination request and allowing the community to take a close look at it. Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid only mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. Flag/vote/edit/retag the posts after consensus is reached. For more info, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: The tag existed longer than that.  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234349/uitableviewcell-automatic-row-height-not-working-after-asynchronous-call) was asked on the 15 and has the tag ans was never edited.  It looks like the tag goes back to December 2014

Comment: Aside: That is when the *tag wiki* was created (not the tag itself), and unless you have 20,000 reputation, the wiki itself gets created by the Community user when the edit suggestion is created and then edited by the user making changes to it once approved.

Comment: IMHO tags should be *libraries*, not *specific methods or classes*. Unless they're ***that*** notable (I haven't heard of any such thing), +1 for burnination.